# Bootstrap grid overlay on zoom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've the following code with bootstrap and jquery imported and the grid system is working fine on my screen. But when I try the zoom in or in smaller screens the buttons are overlaying:

[overlay zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpW98.png)

What I want is:

Smaller components (including smaller texts, etc) in smaller screens without any overlay.

Zoom in area just seeing some components without overlay.

I tried both "container" and "contanier-fluid" and also different meta headers without success . Is there any way to do that just using bootstrap?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body ng-app="angularapp-example">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 3</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 4</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 5</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 6</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 7</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 8</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 9</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 10</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 11</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Buton 12</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Jquery and Bootstrap -->
        <script src="dist/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `col-md-1` class directly to the `a` elements:

```
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 3</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 4</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 5</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 6</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 7</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 8</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 9</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 10</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 11</a>
                    <a href="#" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 btn btn-info">Buton 12</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o5qkq9f7/1/

Comment: But with this solution the buttons are not in the same line in smaller screens. I just want the buttons in the same line (12 rows) but smaller buttons

Comment: See the update. All you have to do is add the col-sm and col-xs classes

Comment: Note you may need to use CSS to make the text align. Just add sytling to the .btn class.

Comment: And note that when you get to really small screens, it is infeasible to keep them on the same line. You should incorporate a dropdown navbar or something. Bootstrap provides solutions for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help.But when I make a zoom the buttons appear in different lines when I just want an "area" zoom